Arduino Mega 2560 time delays counting between events on different pins
I am wondering how I can precisely count time delays between rise events happening on 4 different lines/pins using Input Capture of Arduino Mega 2560. How can I synchronize timer/counters? Appreciate your help and suggestions.

precisely count time delays ... please define precisely

You can't. At least not without modifying the hardware.
The ATmega2560 microcontroller at the hearth of the Arduino Mega has
four input capture units, wired to the input capture pins ICP[1345].
Unfortunately, only two of those pins are routed on the Arduino board.
The table below list the four ICP pins, with their pin numbers on the
TQFP package and on the Arduino board:
   pin     package  Arduino
───────────────────────────
ICP1/PD4     47        --
ICP3/PE7      9        --
ICP4/PL0     35        49
ICP5/PL1     36        48

Unless you manage to solder wires to the missing pins, you won't be able
to use the four input capture units.
As for the synchronization, you have two options:

If you are using the prescaler (i.e. a prescaler factor larger than
one), you should use its “prescaler reset” feature with the TSM bit
(Timer/Counter Synchronization Mode) enabled. This will let you
start the four timers simultaneouly when you clear the TSM bit. See
the MCU datasheet for details.

If you are not using the prescaler, you can just start the four
timers in quick succession, with interrupts disabled. They won't
start quite at the same time, but you can compensate for this when
setting their initial values.


As an example of the second option, the following function starts the
four timers without prescaler and counting in sync:
void init_timers() {
    // Clear the timer configurations.
    TCCR1A = 0; TCCR1B = 0;
    TCCR3A = 0; TCCR3B = 0;
    TCCR4A = 0; TCCR4B = 0;
    TCCR5A = 0; TCCR5B = 0;

    // Set the initial values.
    TCNT1 = 0;
    TCNT3 = 2;
    TCNT4 = 4;
    TCNT5 = 6;

    // Start the timers.
    noInterrupts();
    TCCR1B = _BV(CS10);
    TCCR3B = _BV(CS30);
    TCCR4B = _BV(CS40);
    TCCR5B = _BV(CS50);
    interrupts();
}

The section that starts the timers compiles to this assembly:
cli              ; noInterrupts();
ldi r24, 0x01    ; r24 = _BV(CS10)
sts TCCR1B, r24  ; TCCR1B = r24
sts TCCR3B, r24  ; TCCR3B = r24
sts TCCR4B, r24  ; TCCR4B = r24
sts TCCR5B, r24  ; TCCR5B = r24
sei              ; interrupts();

As the sts instruction completes in two clock cycles, this delay will
compensate for the offset in the initial timer values.
Now, if you don't care about microsecond-level accuracy, you can forget
about the timers and use external interrupts (or pin change interrupts)
and record the times with micros().
